# Extract pixel coordinates in scilab

Tags: scilab

I have extracted edge using image processing then I selected pixel coordinate using **xclick** of extracted edge.Is this correct or there is need of **reverse y axis coordinate**?(Extracted edge is white on black background)
**I want to automatically extracted pixel coordinates of extracted edge** not by mouse selection.Is there is any command available in scilab?(I use canny edge detector and morphological filter to extract edge)

Please give me some suggestions

Thanks

Comment: xclick returns coordinates according to the x and y axes of the graphic window. You can change the direction of the y axis by using `a = gca(); a.axes_reverse = ['off', 'on', 'off']`. I do not understand the rest of your question. If you have extracted edge, it means you know where it is.

Comment: Actually I want to determine pixel coordinates automatically that means if we input the image ,that function or command or program will directly give the pixel coordinates

Comment: But of which pixel? You are using some algorithm to determine some pixel of interest. It should tell you where the pixel is.

Comment: pixel coordinates of extracted profile of water droplet .No,i am using only xcilck command to determine pixel using mouse selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Whether to reverse the y coordinte or not, depends on the further processing. Any coordinate system can be used if you need only relative measurements and the true orientation of your features is not important (e.g. reversing top and bottom makes no difference if you simply want to count objects or droplets). Hovewer if you want to indicate your found features by plotting a dot, or a line, or a rectangle (e.g. with `plot2d` or `xrect`) or a number (e.g. with `xnumb`) over the image, then it's necessary to match the two coordinate sytems. I recommend this second option and to plot your result over the original image, since this is the easiest way to check your results.
2.) Automatic coordinate extraction can be made by the `find` function: it returns those indices of the matrix, where the expression is true.

```
IM=[0,0,0,1;0,0,0,1;0,1,1,1;1,1,0,0];   //edge image, edge = 1, background = 0
disp(IM,"Edge image");
[row,col]=find(IM==1);    //row & column indices where IM = 1 (= edge)
disp([row',col'],"Egde coordinates (row, col)");
```

If your "Egde image" marks the edges not with 1 (or 255, pure white pixel) but with a relatively high number (bright pixel), then you can modify the logical expression of the `find` function to detect pixels with a value above a certain threshold:

```
[row,col]=find(IM>0.8);    //if edges > a certain threshold, e.g. 0.8
```

EDIT: For your specific image:
[image]
Try the following code:

```
imagefile="d:\Attila\PROJECTS\Scilab\Stackoverflow\MORPHOLOGICAL_FILTERING.jpg";
//you have to modify this path!
I=imread(imagefile); 
IM=imcrop(I,[170,100,950,370]);   //discard the thick white border of the image
scf(0); clf(0);
ShowImage(IM,'cropped image');
threshold=100;    //try different values between 0-255 (black - white)
[row,col]=find(IM>threshold);
imheight=size(IM,"r");   //image height
row=imheight-row+1;   //reverse y axes coordinates (0 is at top)
plot2d(col,row,style=0);  //plot over the image (zoom to see the dots)
scf(1); clf(1);  //plot separate graph
plot2d(col,row,style=0);
```

If you play with the threshold parameter, you will see how the darker or whiter pixels are found.

Comment: I have tried but it gives empty matrix .I have upload image in this link please tell me how to extract pixel coordinates of white edge. http://s3.postimg.org/fw44u6qqr/MORPHOLOGICAL_FILTERING.png

Comment: @khushbu I edited my answer. Is it a solution for your problem?

Comment: Ok, its useful, but it gives numbers of pixel coordinate of an edge at one single point (as zoom shows) while  i want to select only single pixel coordinate at one point .Ialso want to know how to select [170,100,950,370] so that I can choose for other images and this image to left a single pixel coordinate at one position mainly at contact point of horizontal line because i need for curve fitting purpose.Thanks

Comment: @khushbu Actually I defined the selected area with rubberbox: it was one of your previous question how to use it. I don't know what kind of curve fitting algorithm you want to use, but if it's something with least squares optimization or other nonlinear regression method, then the multiple points (pixels) at the edge should not cause problem at all: the algorithm should find the centerline of that wider area too. I suggest you to try the fitting first to see if there is a real need to narrow down the line. If yes, then ask an other question (not here in the comments), to be seen by others too.